# eval not running in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eval

I am having problems setting  the educationflag variable to 1. The problem I am solving is not to call enableEdit.php file if flag is 1.

I want to set the flag to 1 when the control comes in the if condition. Right now the control comes in the if condition but does not set the variable to 1. My code is printed below. I

```
var educationFlag=0;

function editEducation(class){

   //I send education in class variable. So class ='education';
   var condition=eval(class+'Flag');
   if ( condition == 0 ){
      $.ajax({
        url: "enableEdit.php",
        data: "class="+class,
        success: function(msg) {    
        }
    })
      eval(class+'Flag'=1);
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I see, all I have to do is call the `editEducation` function with my malicious code in the argument. Ok, got it. Thanks `:)` (Not that I wouldn't be able to figure this out by viewing your source code directly on your page ... )

Comment: It's possible I'm missing something but as far as I know "class" is used for defining a class. It looks like you want class to be your own personal variable for storing "education." If that's the case, you may be getting problems from misusing keywords as variables.

Comment: Also you hardcode the name of the function so no need to pass a variable unless you have a generic function editClass(...)

Comment: @MikeC there is no `class` in javascript. it's not a keyword

Comment: Any time you ever want to use `eval()`, you are almost certainly making a big mistake. `eval()` is a security risk, it causes performance issues, and it makes your code difficult to debug. But most of all, it is almost *never* necessary to actually use it: there is always a better way. It is occasionally useful, but never in situations like this.

Comment: @Raynos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: @Raynos then what is this? http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/classes.html

Comment: @Mike: Even better. I could not find that at developer.mozilla.org

Comment: @MikeC Prepiotary language extensions that mozilla made. There is no `class` in EcmaScript

Comment: @Mike It's a draft that didn't get implemented. The ECMAScript 3/5 specs do *not* make use of the `class` keyword. It's nonetheless mentioned in the specs as part of a group named *`FutureReservedWord`*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without trying to fix your underlying issues and stop the pollution of the global scope, this should work. Please note I have renamed the [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) class to varPrefix

```
var educationFlag=0;

function editClass(varPrefix) {
   if (window[varPrefix+'Flag'] === 0 ){
      $.ajax({
        url: "enableEdit.php",
        data: "class="+varPrefix,
        success: function(msg) {    
          window[varPrefix+'Flag']=1;
        }
    })
  }
}
```

I send education in varPrefix variable. So varPrefix ='education';

`editClass("education") ...`

Comment: You don't need a typeof check on the global variable because your accessing it as a property of `window`

Comment: You say that is why I do not get to the catch phrase here?  http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hj9LX/

Comment: yes. If you try `fooFlag` it will throw an exception. If you try `window.fooFlag` it will just return undefined. Only accessing undeclared variables throws errors. Accessing properties that don't exist just returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of the `class` variable that is passed into the function? I'll make an educated guess that it's going to be something like `education`? Is that right?

In that case, the first `eval()` will effectively be this:

```
var condition=eval('educationFlag');
```

and the second will be this:

```
eval('educationFlag'=1);
```

The second is failing because the `=1` part is not in the string. That's the short answer, which directly solves your problem.

However, the *better* answer is that `eval()` is the wrong thing to use. You should never use `eval()` for this kind of thing. Since `educationFlag` is a global variable, you can access it via the `window` object as an array element: this means you can do exactly the same thing, without having to use risky `eval()` at all.

You can reference it like this: `window['educationFlag']`

Therefore, your `eval()` lines can be replaced like this:

```
var condition=window[class+'Flag'];
```

and

```
window[class+'Flag']=1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it does help. See my identical answer (which does not use the reserved word class)

Comment: @mplungjan -- yes, I spotted it, and gave you +1. I've left my answer in place because I've given more explanation of the issue than your answer.

Comment: Right, I missed the `Flag'=1)` instead of `Flag=1')` from your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do in your code... You say you want to "not call enableEdit.php if flag is 1". If that's the case, why can't you just do:

`if(flag == 1) { ... }`

And get rid of your `eval` statements?